# How are groundtruths (heatmaps and PAFs) in pose estimation generated?

Tags: computer-vision, pose-estimation, keypoint

I hope you're doing well in this time of the pandemic.

I'm working with keypoint processing; more specifically, trying to identify the location and orientation of an object based on its keypoints. I have read some research papers and saw that they use pre-labeled images from CoCo.

I am having trouble understanding how are the PAFs and keypoints are generated in that pre-labeled dataset.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!